# Kafka Joins - How can we achive it?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have below topics in Kafka(**10 partitions each**) and want to join them as given in below example? Could someone please advise how this can be done?

**Topic:"orders"**

[image: Order1, quantity,tickerString,Price O1,10,AMAZ,10.2 O2 20,MSFT,10.3 O3,10,GOOG,20.1]

**Topic: "referencedata"**

[image: tickerString,tickerId AMAZ,1234 MSFT,5678 GOOG,9012 FACE,3456]

**Joined Topic:"merged_ref_orders"**
[image: Order1, quantity,tickerString,Price,tickerId O1,10,AMAZ,10.2,1234 O2 20,MSFT,10.3,5678 O3,10,GOOG,20.1,9012]

Basically, we are loading all of the orders and reference data into a hash map and then joining them. This is causing lots of performance issue when there are lots of orders. I came through something such as KTable/GlobalKTable but not sure how does it operate internally.

1. **KTable/GlobalKTable would load all the data in the heap memory**? If yes, then it won't help keep the java memory low.
   Could some one please advise how this scenario can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to turn the referencedata topic into a KTable keyed on tickerString. This means that you will have a materialised view that it is auto-updated when new referencedata are arriving into the topic. Also it means that you can query the KTable using the key (i.e. tickerString). Then you can create a KStream consuming from orders topic and join this stream to the referencedata KTable and push the resulting join to a new topic (i.e. merged_ref_orders).

Key both the referencedata KTable and the orders topic using the same key (i.e. tickerString), so that you do not have to use a GlobalKTable. A regular KTable (much more scalable) will be enough. Using a KTable with a Rocks DB will keep your memory usage very low as it utilising the partitioned data and also stores locally to your jvm data to a RocksDB.

Two official confluent examples how to join/ enrich a KStream to a KTable:
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/6.0.1-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/PageViewRegionLambdaExample.java

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/6.0.1-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/microservices/InventoryService.java

Comment: If my answer helped you and answers your question pls mark it. Cheers!